# How to open SSH session in console application?

Tags: .net, ssh, console-application

I need to develop a .net console application which can authenticate a SSH session and provide access to the user (give control to user so he can execute the commands as needed).

If we can generate a console app, we can integrate this with out PAM solution which will automatically invoke this exe and supply username and password.

Please suggest a best library for this. I have tried renci and ssh.net, but unable to achieve these results.